# Extract data from ajax

Tags: python, python-3.x, ajax, scrapy

I'm trying to extract data (title, price and description) from ajax but it doesn't work even by changing the user agent

Link : https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_header/
Ajax (data want to extract) : https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/

```
import scrapy


class UseragentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'useragent'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/']
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"


    def parse(self, response):
        cardb= response.xpath("//div[@class='card-body']")
        for thing in cardb:
            title= thing.xpath(".//h3")
            yield {'title' : title}
```

Error log :

```
2020-09-07 20:34:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-09-07 20:34:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-09-07 20:34:39 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-09-07 20:34:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://scrapingclub.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-09-07 20:34:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/> (referer: None)
2020-09-07 20:34:40 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Comment: if it needs AJAX request then it may need header `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AJAX` requests should send header

```
 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

but not all servers check it. But this server check it. But it doesn't check `User-Agent`.

Server sends data as `JSON` so `xpath` will be useless.

---

I tested it with `requests` instead of `scrapy` because it was simpler for me.

```
import requests

headers = {
    #'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

url = 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

print(data)
print('type:', type(data))
print('keys:', data.keys())
print('--- manually ---')
print('price:', data['price'])
print('title:', data['title'])
print('--- for-loop ---')
for key, value in data.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
```

Result:

```
{'img_path': '/static/img/00959-A.jpg', 'price': '$24.99', 'description': 'Blouse in airy, crinkled fabric with a printed pattern. Small stand-up collar, concealed buttons at front, and flounces at front. Long sleeves with buttons at cuffs. Rounded hem. 100% polyester. Machine wash cold.', 'title': 'Crinkled Flounced Blouse'}
type: <class 'dict'>
keys: dict_keys(['img_path', 'price', 'description', 'title'])
--- manually ---
price: $24.99
title: Crinkled Flounced Blouse
--- for-loop ---
img_path: /static/img/00959-A.jpg
price: $24.99
description: Blouse in airy, crinkled fabric with a printed pattern. Small stand-up collar, concealed buttons at front, and flounces at front. Long sleeves with buttons at cuffs. Rounded hem. 100% polyester. Machine wash cold.
title: Crinkled Flounced Blouse
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same with `Scrapy`. I use function `start_requests()` to create `Request()` with header `'X-Requested-With'`

You can put all code in one file and run `python script.py` without creating project.

```
import scrapy
import json

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/'

        headers = {
            #'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }

        yield scrapy.http.Request(url, headers=headers)
        
    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        data = response.json()

        print(data)
        print('type:', type(data))
        print('keys:', data.keys())
        print('--- manually ---')
        print('price:', data['price'])
        print('title:', data['title'])
        print('--- for-loop ---')
        for key, value in data.items():
            print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    #'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    #'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same using setting [DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#default-request-headers)

```
import scrapy
import json

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)
        #print('headers:', response.request.headers)
        
        data = response.json()

        print(data)
        print('type:', type(data))
        print('keys:', data.keys())
        print('--- manually ---')
        print('price:', data['price'])
        print('title:', data['title'])
        print('--- for-loop ---')
        for key, value in data.items():
            print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
            #'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    #'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    #'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !!